# Adding an ImageIcon to a JPanel using a variable as the file path

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, embedded-resource, imageicon

I have a csv file containing the file names of all my images. I want to extract the file names from that file and use them to add the corresponding image to my GUI. I have a lot of images so I can't just type out all the file paths.

It works if I use

```
img = new ImageIcon("resources/imagename.jpg");
```

but not if I use

```
String fileName = "resources/" + fileNameExtractedFromCSVFile;
img = new ImageIcon(fileName);
```

It's extracting the file name just fine, it just won't use it to locate the image. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: oops yes that was a typo.

Comment: Please make sure you concatenate ".jpg" if it is not extracted from the CSV.

Comment: It is included in the file name extracted from the CSV.

Comment: You have a CSV file with the list of image name and you seem to think passing the URL reference of this file to ImageIcon will magically read the file, know what each column in the file means and read the images for you...find me in the documentation where ImageIcon(URL) does this...

Comment: I'm sending ImageIcon a string of the path taken from the CSV. (which is allowed)  I'm not trying to send a CSV file to ImageIcon... I'm not a total idiot.

Comment: please share your csv file if you dont mind

Answer (score 0):

inspect the value of fileNameExtractedFromCSVFile before using it. seems like its not getting populated properly.  If you are using an IDE, try to run the code in DEBUG mode and put a break point on this line to see what the value of the variables are.

Comment: It's populating the variable just as it's supposed to.

Comment: @user3586210 But you're not reading the file contents, you're asking ImageIcon to treat the CSV file as an image file, which it isn't

Comment: if that's the case and the image file exists in the resources folder, i see nothing wrong with the code. is the image readable? is the extension correct?  @user3586210 - The ImageIcon constructor takes a string filename, so its ok the way he is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If I did understood you correctly you need something like this please see the demo below and the code for it. In addition please created images package in your application.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**add this method to your class to read csv**

```
   public void csvread() throws IOException 
    {
        File file = new File("filenames.csv");
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), 
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] array = line.split(",");
        jTextArea1.append(array[0]+"\n");
    }

    }
```

**button csv read action**

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    try {
        csvread();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ImageDisplay.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

**text area mouse released get selected text and display image on jlabel**

```
private void jTextArea1MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         

    if (jTextArea1.getSelectedText() != null) {

        String s = jTextArea1.getSelectedText();

        ImageIcon imageselect = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/" + s));
        jLabel2.setIcon(imageselect);

    } else {
        jLabel4.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```